# I added a facebook registration plugin to my website, but I have no idea where the info goes once a person completes registration

Tags: facebook, plugins, registration

I've checked the email account linked to the app I created (needed to get an app id)...nothing.  Nothing in any of my facebook pages or profile inboxes/notifications.  It's like the information disappears into an abyss.  I read something about creating a canvas page...which i did...but I don't see how that would make a difference.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should handle the facebook JSON callback, this plugin will just allow you to registered your users with their facebook account:

take a look at: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/ section: Reading the data

Comment: I looked at that link and didn't see any indication of where they data GOES...just how it will look once it arrives.  I customized my reg form to ask specific questions, so I want to know where the data goes so I can read the answers to the questions.  Make sense?  I'm not a techie so you'll have to excuse me if my question seems stupid to someone with a lot of background in this sort of stuff.

Answer (score 0):

did you configure your my sql or your sql server or the oracle db which you have on you host according to the exact order of the fb registration system.cause when they click access my data alltheir data is transferred to your db. thats how it works. if ure db is not configured it will go to abyss.